# How to fix dots covering application label on app menu

Tags: 20.04

I just upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and then when I run the application, there will be an orange dot covering the text on the app menu: does anyone know how to fix it? Maybe there is a way to fix it.

[image: dots]

I've tried to change the icon size on Settings/Appearance, change the display resolution and the dots is still covering the label

Icon size small:
[image: icon size small]

Icon size big:
[image: icon size big]

1360x768 resolution:
[image: 1360x768 resolution]

1024x768 resolution:
[image: 1024x768 resolution]

Comment: The dot definitely is supposed to be UNDER the text line. First go to Settings/Appearance/Icons Size and make them smallet then bigger and let us know. To test if this is a bug can you change the screen resolution (try at least 2 differens resolutions) and let us know also.

Comment: i was change the icon size, but not affect to the app menu. i change the resolution too, and still not working :(

Comment: That is very strange. You should report it as a bug, even though it may only happen to a few users. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Reporting_non-crash_hardware_and_desktop_application_bugs